# Build error on org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.feature

Tags: eclipse, licensing, jsdt

I cloned eclipse/webtools.jsdt.core on GitHub. (https://github.com/eclipse/webtools.jsdt.core)

Then imported it to Juno-RCP on Mac OS X 10.6, and tried to build and export it by using org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.feature/feature.xml .

But I got an error that said "Unable to find feature "org.eclipse.license" with version in range [1.0.0,1.0.1)." .

What is the cause of this error?
What should I do to solve this problem?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer on wtp-dev mailing-list. http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/wtp-dev/msg08663.html

Get 'features/org.eclipse.license/' in this repo: git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.git .

And just import 'features/org.eclipse.license/' subdirectory as a project.

Thanks